How to write iptables u32 rules to handle IPv4 GRE packets with an IPv6 payload?
I'm currently working on upgrading my service to support dual-stack (IPv4 and IPv6) as part of a project. My service currently supports only IPv4 and uses iptables with the u32 module to filter packets based on specific patterns.
For IPv4, I handle packets with the structure IP | GRE | IP | TCP. Below is an example of an existing rule I use to match such packets:
iptables ${WAIT_ARGS} --table ${TABLE} --insert SERVER_OUR 1 --jump SHA_CHECK --match u32 --u32 
6 & 0xFF = 47
&& 4 & 0x3FFF = 0
&& 0 >> 22 & 0x3C @ 0 & 0xFFFF = 0x0800
&& 0 >> 22 & 0x3C @ 14 & 0xFF = 6

Now, I want to handle packets with the structure IP | GRE | IPv6 | TCP, where the IPv6 payload is encapsulated within an IPv4 GRE packet. I have two specific questions:
Can I use the same u32 module in iptables to check whether the payload is IPv6? For example, would a rule like this work to identify IPv6 in the GRE payload?
0 >> 22 & 0x3C @ 0 & 0xFFFF = 0x86DD 
Once I identify the payload as IPv6, how can I check whether the next header in the IPv6 payload is TCP? Do I need to mark these packets and direct them to a separate chain for processing by an IPv6-specific module, or is there another way to achieve this?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
I was expecting some suggestions so that I can sort this out.
